# Two fingered swipe v. one fingered drag in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

In my app I have a `UIView` derived class `Canvas` that uses `touchesBegan: withEvent:`, `touchesMoved: withEvent:`, and `touchesEnded: withEvent:` to draw in the canvas. I also want to use a swipe to load the previous (or next) canvas in an array. I tried setting up the following gesture (and a similar one for right):

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer* leftSwipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector(pageFlipNext)];
leftSwipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
leftSwipe.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[_canvas addGestureRecognizer: leftSwipe];
[leftSwipe release];
```

But my two fingered swipes are still being treated as one-fingered drawing instructions.
How do I get my app to handle the two-fingered swipe correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would get started verifying whether `_canvas.multipleTouchEnabled` is set to `YES`. If it isn't, set it to `YES`.

You might also want to consider

```
leftSwipe.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

This will delay the touches to be sent to the `_canvas` until the gesture fails. You can also use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and do something like this,

```
[pan requireGestureRecognizerToFail:leftSwipe];
```

Comment: I was fixated on the swipe, so I didn't even check the pan, but I think it'll work even better, since it will allow the user to page continuously by continuing to drag.
And the delay flag stops the stray one-finger touches.
Thanks!

Comment: Something else that helped (for those who are trying something similar):
In the selector message that gets called on the pan, I have an `NSLock` check around a class-instance `BOOL`. If it's set, I unlock and return. If it's not set, I lock and do the page flip. Then I detach a new thread that calls a selector that sleeps for 0.1s then unsets the `BOOL`.
That keeps a long pan from showing up as multiple pans.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can use [UIPanGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPanGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> UIPanGestureRecognizer is a concrete
>   subclass of UIGestureRecognizer that
>   looks for panning (dragging) gestures.
>   The user must be pressing one or more
>   fingers on a view while they pan it.